# Optimize SQLite Table Access Efficiency in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

My app reads dozens of SQLite databases ranging in size from 1MB to 100MB with a simple table structure like,

"create table dictionary(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, topics, definition)"

On startup the app reads all the databases to extract the "topics" column data. With the DB configured as above extracting the topic data is a lengthy process. It seems the whole DB file is being read to just access the relatively small "topics" column.

If I add another table with just the topics data,

"create table dictionary(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, topics)"

access is quicker. However, if I make another DB file with just the topics column, access is much quicker. I don't really want to use two files to access a single DB.

My questions,
Does table creation order affect the speed of access?

Is there a way to read only the part of the file that has the queried table/column thus saving time and hard dive grinding?

Is it possible to read a small table/column from a huge file nearly as quick as the small table alone from a small file? And if so, how?

Thanks,

Comment: What select statement are you using? If you put some code here to show the problem, you'll get better answers.

Comment: Just a basic statement:

cur.execute('SELECT topics FROM dictionary')

Comment: There are some GREAT answers on SO about PRAGMA's for SQLite that make it run a lot quicker, just do a search.

Comment: Thanks, I looked but most Pragmas that are mentioned for optimization like Journal Mode and Synchronous deal with writing to the DB. My app only reads from it. Do you have any specific answers in mind?

Comment: Would creating an additional index on the topics column help?

Comment: @XLT Yes, I tried an index but it did not help the access speed. It only made the file bigger.